# ASP.NET MVC3: can Action accept mulitple model parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

For example:

```
class MyContoller
{
    [MyCustomAttribute]
    public ActionResult MyAction(ModelX fromRequest, ModelY fromSession, ModelZ fromCookie)
    {
       string productId = fromRequest.ProductId;
       string userId = fromSession.UserId;
       string cultureName = fromCookie.CultureName;
    }
}
```

Reason:

I don't want to visit Request, Session and HttpContext in the controllers, and the default idea of MVC3 which passing models to actions is very great.

I want the number of parameters of MyAction is easy to change. For example, if I add a new parameter, the system will try to look for values in Request, Session or Cookies by the name or type of the parameter (I think custom ModelBinders may be required for cookie values) and pass the filled model to my action. I don't have to write extra code.

Can the custom attribute (MyCustomAttribute in the example) accomplish this idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I follow you about the custom attribute.  What are you expecting the custom attribute to do?

Yes, an action method can take as many model parameters as you want.  Obviously, only one can be bound in any given request (because a view can only have one model).  Whichever one is found first will be bound, and the others will be null.

So let's say you have the following:

```
public class ModelX {
    public string X {get;set;}
}

public class ModelY {
    public string Y {get;set;}
}

public class ModelZ {
    public string Z {get;set;}
}
```

And you have an action method like this:

```
public ActionResult DoIt(ModelX x, ModelY y, ModelZ z)
{
    return View();
}
```

And in your DoIt.cshtml you have the following:

```
@model ModelZ

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Z)
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

If you type something into the textbox and submit, then the model binder will bind a ModelZ with the value you entered and ModelX and ModelY will be null.

If you mean can an action method bind multiple models simultaneously, then I would have to ask you.. How exactly do you plan to have a view have more than one model?  You can certainly create a wrapper model to contain the multiple models, but a view can only have one.

Comment: I thought I could do something in the attribute, like collectiong parameters from Request, Session or Cookie, before the action is ready to execute.

Comment: Thanks, can I make Session or Cookie as the source the of Model's values?

Comment: @Zach - So what you mean is you want to get parameters fed into your action method from different sources, not that you want multiple models.  A view can only have one model.

Comment: This leads to another question, if I have a page view which contains multiple partial views (each partial view has a model). Of course, I need to create and fill these models, but how I can pass them to the partial views?

Answer (score 1):

Create a composite ViewModel class that incorporates `ModelX`, `ModelY` and `ModelZ`.  You can then populate  an instance of your new ViewModel class, and pass that to your controller method.

```
public class XYZViewModel
{
    public ModelX fromRequest { get; set; }
    public ModelY fromSession { get; set; }
    public ModelZ fromCookie { get; set; }
}


public class MyController
{
    [MyCustomAttribute]
    public ActionResult MyAction(XYZViewModel myModel)
    {
       string productId = myModel.fromRequest.ProductId;
       string userId = myModel.fromSession.UserId;
       string cultureName = myModel.fromCookie.CultureName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, My main purpose is to make the action's parameter list as free as possible without having to create extra classes.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're trying to solve more than the problem I've identified.  Why don't you want to visit Request, Session and HttpContext in the controllers?  Seems like the logical place to get that information.

Comment: I read some articles mentioning that HttpContext and related objects are hard to test. So I want put the code which collects parameters in dedicated classes. These clasess will do one thing: reading parameters from HttpContext and saving the values into models, without any other logic.

Comment: HttpContext and related objects are already tested; they are part of the framework.  If you want wrapper classes for these objects, you have to write them.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I meant the code using HttpContext is hard to test, not HttpContext itself.

Comment: But if you write a wrapper class, you'll just be papering over that problem anyway, won't you?  Somewhere, something has to access HttpContext.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass multiple parameters to your controller action, yes.  The key is to make sure they are properly serialized in the request.  If you're using a form, that means using the Html helper methods.

For example, let's say you want an action like this:

```
public ActionResult Multiple(ModelA a, ModelB b)
{
    // ...
}
```

You could create simple partial view for each model:

```
@model MyProject.Models.ModelA
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Then in your **Multiple** view, render the partial views like so:

```
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("Multiple", "MyController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Partial("A", new MyProject.Models.ModelA())
    @Html.Partial("B", new MyProject.Models.ModelB())
    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
}
```

I set the method to **GET** here so that you can easily see how MVC passes the parameters.  If you submit the form, you'll see that MVC successfully deserializes each object.